# AMQP High level client for Node.JS - Looking for the "best choice"

Tags: node.js, amqp

I'm new in the RabbitMQ (AMQP) world and need to build a complex nodeJS application and trying to understand if its better to use the most popular(?) amqplib client or to use other alternatives.

I am asking here because i don't want to choose a lib that may be deprecated in the near future or a lib without wide support. i found

In other hand, i don't want to waste time on building my own common central "helper" from scratch.

I found [NabbbitMQ](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nabbitmq) but i don't think its popular enough for me.

Can you advice?

Answer (score 1):

I use RabbitMQ in my production code. I would highly recommend it over other services. It gets slow sometimes on free tier but on paid instance you will face no problems.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your comment. I am also using RabbitMQ but i am asking regarding the client for it for NodeJS applications...

Comment: I am using : https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqplib and would highly recommend it.